# Recommendations for creating Application Index Page (Map) for WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am designing a WPF app, which will have Independent utilities/tools which serves its own purpose. I wanted to create something like an **Index page which has a link to all apps** (forms) and **each app** will have it's **link back to the Index Page.**

The Straightforward way I could think of is to have buttons which navigates the form back and forth. I was wondering if there is a recommended way of doing it ? Say, using an XML to construct these links dynamically ?

Comment: You can use a **plugin** approach where each app is a plugin and the main program loads all of them.

Comment: I get what you are saying. In case say if I add a new plugin how does the main program load and Especially LINK it. I am not a Developer, would you care to elaborate ?

Comment: The main program detects all plugins in a folder, then you can select (with code) how they are going to be loaded (all, only one, only type X...) then you will have a list of loaded plugins, this list can be showed in a ListView and when you click in an item you could show its GUI.